# Can ripple currency units be integers?

Tags: ripple, iou

I understand with Ripple that anyone on the network can offer their own currency.  Someone cited the example of airline frequent flier miles.

Airline miles, in my experience, come in whole numbers.  I.e. 2000 miles, not 1999.5 miles.

If I start trading miles on Ripple, someone could easily offer to buy or sell in fractional units.  So balances in ripple wallets could be 1999.5 miles, right?

Is there any way in Ripple to force the units of a particular currency to be integers?

I'm asking about what appears in the wallets.  I know that within the system the units are integers.  I.e. 1 XRP = 1,000,000 drops.  I'm asking about the balances shown to users in their wallets.

Comment: You can round down when processing orders and let your users know this.

Comment: As @JacobTorba says, this is what TTBit does with his [DYM currency](https://ripple.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2292).

Comment: Instead of integers it would be better if each currency could specify their divisibility. I.e 1.0 for airline miles, 0.01 for USD, 10.0 for XAU from a gateway with only 10 oz bars, etc. However, I for one like the ability to have sub-cent accounting for my USD and other currencies. Probably better if it was an option on trade offers themselves for someone not wanting to get or give a fractional amount for a specific offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gateways can refuse to issue or redeem fractional amounts and users can refuse to pay them. But there is no authority to say to someone "you may not hold a fractional amount of this currency". Nobody can stop you from holding fractional amounts if you wish to.